# How to correctly use LEFT JOIN IS NULL or NOT EXISTS in this query?

Tags: sql, database, join, left-join

After a few dozens of tries I still got wrong results, so I thought I'd better ask for help.

Tables:

```
labels
    id, user_id, name

messages_labels
    id, message_id, label_id
```

`labels.id` refers to `message_labels.label_id`

How to get the correct results unused labels given a message-id and a user_id? By unused labels I mean labels that do not have an entry in `message_labels` for a given message-id, basically that only select labels to add to the message that are not in use for this message yet.

This means something like...

```
SELECT l.id, l.name
FROM labels l
INNER/LEFT JOIN messages_labels ml ON (l.id=ml.label_id)
WHERE... user_id=:user_id ...

... and `message_id <> :message_id`
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `LEFT JOIN` on the label_id and the message id, anything without an ML record is what you want

```
SELECT 
    l.id, l.name
FROM labels l
LEFT JOIN message_labels ml
    ON l.id = ml.label_id
    AND message_id = :message_id
WHERE l.user_id = :user_id
AND ml.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

One method:

```
SELECT labels.*, count(messages_labels.id) AS mlid
FROM labels
JOIN messages_labels ON labels.id = messages_labels.label_id
WHERE (user_id = :user_id) AND (message_id = :message_id)
GROUP BY labels.id
HAVING (mlid = 0)
```

if I'm readin your question correctly.

Comment: wouldn't this return 0 results every time?

Comment: it'd return the labels that have no associated messages.

Comment: wouldn't those be eliminated by the message_id in the where clause?